# Javascript - assign function to variable (reference/value)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the definition of a function:

```
var a = function(){alert('a');};
var b = a;
b = function(){alert('b');};
```

This results in the variable `a` keeping it's original assignment i.e. the function producing `alert('a')`.

Is there any way of passing around a reference to a javascript function so that I can alter it later?

Comment: No, you really can't do this with a simple variable. You can keep a function reference as an object property, and then manipulate that property value.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, that's not what he wants. He wants to overwrite A with B on the third line.

Comment: I think prototype is good choice for this, is not?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes [limit]

Comment: @NathanP.: Ah, I see now.  :)

Comment: Hi, yes I want to update a...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would you expect the value of `a` to change after the following snippet? Snippet in question:

```
var a = 10;
var b = a;
var b = 20;
```

No, right? So why would you expect reassigning `b` to *also* affect `a`?

After line `1`, you have `a` pointing to a function instance:

[image]

After line `2`, you have a new variable `b`, *also* pointing to the same function instance. So now you have two variables, both pointing to the same instance:

[image]

After line `3`, you have reassigned `b` to something else (a new function), but `a` *is still pointing* to the original function:

[image]

You can do what you want by doing something like this:

```
var func = function() { alert("a"); };

var a = function() { func(); };
var b = a;

func = function() { alert("b"); };
```

Now calling `a()` or `b()` will alert the string `b`.

Comment: According to you 'a is still pointing to the original function:' then why last line alerts 20?

Comment: It shouldn't be alerting `20` anywhere; the code is only alerting the string literals `a` or `b`.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But is there any way to accomplish what I want, more than one variable pointing to the same function, In such a way that when I update one, the other changes?

Comment: @Marcus Yes, you can do this by wrapping the function in another and then changing the inner function. I will post some code.

Comment: @VivinPaliath I was with your exmaple not with OP.

Comment: @SumanBogati Are you talking about the first 3 lines? After the first 3 lines, the value of `a` is `10` and the value of `b` is `20`; the value of `a` does not change.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Thanks for this, I need to think for a while, but I think there is an accepted answer coming your way :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way of passing around a reference to a javascript function so that I can alter it later?

There is no way to do this. Javascript does not have "pointers". It has reference **values**, and as such, `a` is a reference to the **value** of a, not to the memory location of a.

So, for this set of instructions

```
var a = function(){alert('a');};
var b = a;
b = function(){alert('b');};
```

this is the progression

```
//a is stored at some memory location
var a;

//b is stored at some memory location
var b;

//the memory location where a is stored has its value updated
a = function(){alert('a');};

//the memory location where b is stored has its value updated
//from the value stored at a's memory location
b = a;

//the memory location where b is stored has its value updated
b = function(){alert('b');};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could produce the result you're looking for like this:

```
var fn = function() { alert('a'); };
var a = function() { fn(); };
var b = a;
fn = function(){ alert('b'); };
```

This code would produce the desired effect you're looking for because they'll both call fn() and you're changing the common underlying reference.